# URLs other than index cause 500 internal server error

Tags: install

I installed craft according to the documentation but when I tried to access example.com/admin I get following error

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer:
>   http://example.com/

Every subpage like example.com/about has the same behavior. Only example.com works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I changed the .htaccess-file after I found the [same problem with cakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850845/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio). I just had to add `RewriteBase /` after `RewriteEngine On` so the .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    # Send would be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If your site is [multilingual](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide) (i.e., if you have subfolders like `/en/`, `/de/`, etc. with indivudual .htaccess files in them), this fix requires you to add you the locale's segment to the specific rewrite base of each .htaccess file (e.g. `RewriteBase /en/` and so on.)

Now it works fine.

Comment: Feels wrong changing the provided htaccess file! But hey if it works.

Comment: I have to do this on Rackspace CloudSites servers, but not on any of my other servers local or remote. Kinda annoying but this fix does work so there is that.