# After migration to staging, requesting any page other than Home results in 500 error

Tags: error-message, install, apache

I've developed my site locally and now need to migrate to staging. The Home page is displaying correctly so I would assume that a database connection is not the issue. But requesting `{staging_url}/{any_segment}` results in a 500 Internal Server error.

Here I'm setting the environment in `index.php`:

```
if (substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], -strlen('.dev')) === '.dev') {
    define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
} else if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'staging.blah.com') {
    define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'staging');
} else {
    define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
}
```

Here's my `general.php`:

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'extraAllowedFileExtensions' => 'vcf',
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    ),
    'development' => array(
        'devMode' => true,
        'siteUrl' => 'http://blah.dev',
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'baseUrl' => 'http://blah.dev',
        ),
    ),
    'staging' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://staging.blah.com',
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'baseUrl' => 'http://staging.blah.com',
        ),
    ),
    'production' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://blah.com',
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'baseUrl' => 'http://blah.com',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause of your issue, but `if (substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], -strlen('.dev')) === '.dev' !== FALSE)` isn't valid PHP syntax.

Comment: Ha I shortened that line before posting because it caused a wrap in the preview- I thought I had the right syntax but I guess not. Anyway, I don't think that's it.

Can you please help me understand the difference between siteUrl and baseUrl?

Also, could this possibly be due to a bad Settings > General > Site URL value when I did the db export / import? I added the siteUrl override after the migration.

Comment: This has something to do with index.php being absent in the requested URL.

Comment: @subtlegusto Could you add your fix as an answer so this question is marked as answered/complete. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This is solved by [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/urls-other-than-index-cause-500-internal-server-error).

The common thread here is Rackspace Cloud Sites, which apparently needs a `RewriteBase /` instruction in `.htaccess`.

Thanks @maxx and @christopher-healey